# Symfony 4 - JWT not found with LexikJWTAuthenticationBundle

Tags: php, symfony, jwt, lexikjwtauthbundle, nelmioapidocbundle

Good afternoon,

I try to use LexikJWTAuthenticationBundle in my project and I have a problem with the token which is not generated. I have set the private & public keys in var/jwt directory.

The API returns this response when I try use the login route :

```
{
    "code": 401,
    "message": "JWT Token not found"
}
```

Apache Virtualhost :

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName ypostirixi
    DocumentRoot "/var/www/ypostirixi/public"

    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{HTTP:Authorization} ^(.*)
    RewriteRule .* - [e=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%1]
</VirtualHost>
```

.htaccess file in public directory:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On

    RewriteCond %{HTTP:Authorization} ^(.*)
    RewriteRule .* - [e=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%1]

    # Send would-be 404 requests to Craft
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule (.+) index.php?p=$1 [QSA,L]
</IfModule>
```

security.yaml security:

```
encoders:
    App\Entity\User:
        algorithm: bcrypt
providers:
    doctrine_provider:
        entity:
            class: App\Entity\User
            property: email

firewalls:
    dev:
        pattern: ^/(_(profiler|wdt)|css|images|js)/
        security: false
    api_doc:
        pattern:  ^/api/doc
        security: false
    api:
        pattern:   ^/api
        stateless: true
        guard:
            authenticators:
                - lexik_jwt_authentication.jwt_token_authenticator
    main:
        pattern:   ^/
        stateless: true
        guard:
            authenticators:
                - lexik_jwt_authentication.jwt_token_authenticator
        provider: doctrine_provider

access_control:
    - { path: ^/api/login, roles: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
    - { path: ^/api,       roles: IS_AUTHENTICATED_FULLY }
```

I expect to successfully use the login route and generate a valid token on the others routes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you for your help.

I have discover a problem about this upgrade, but I have a solution.

In lexik_jwt_authentication.yaml file :

```yaml
lexik_jwt_authentication:
    secret_key: '%env(resolve:JWT_SECRET_KEY)%'
    public_key: '%env(resolve:JWT_PUBLIC_KEY)%'
    pass_phrase: '%env(JWT_PASSPHRASE)%'
    token_ttl: '%env(JWT_TTL)%'
    token_extractors:
        authorization_header:
            enabled: true
            prefix:  '%env(JWT_TOKEN_PREFIX)%'
            name:    Authorization
    user_identity_field: email
```

Answer (score 1):

You are not allowing anonymous access to any firewalls. You should add anonymous option to your main firewall.

```yaml
    main:
        pattern:   ^/
        stateless: true
        anonymous: true
        guard:
            authenticators:
                - lexik_jwt_authentication.jwt_token_authenticator
        provider: doctrine_provider
```

Answer (score 1):

- Maybe you forgot to configure firewall of login in section firewalls or login parameters (email as username) ..

***check with this***

1 **config/packages/security.yaml**

```
    firewalls:
        login:
            pattern:  ^/api/login
            stateless: true
            anonymous: true
            form_login:
                check_path:               /api/login_check
                username_parameter: email
                password_parameter: password
                success_handler:          lexik_jwt_authentication.handler.authentication_success
                failure_handler:          lexik_jwt_authentication.handler.authentication_failure
                require_previous_session: false

        api:
            pattern:   ^/api
            stateless: true
            guard:
               authenticators:
                   - lexik_jwt_authentication.jwt_token_authenticator
        access_control:
            - { path: ^/api/login$, role: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
            - { path: ^/api/, role: IS_AUTHENTICATED_FULLY }
```

2 **config/routes.yaml**

```
api_login_check:
    path: /api/login_check
```

3 **Test it with curl**

```
X POST -H "Content-Type: application/json" http://localhost/api/login_check -d '{"email":"user@example.com","password":"pass"}'
```

**NB: if not working for you , maybe you skipped a step on the configuration or you did not configure the bundle properly , You must see on the documentation https://github.com/lexik/LexikJWTAuthenticationBundle/blob/master/Resources/doc/index.md#installation**